# laptop shuts off with new battery

Tags: laptop, shutdown, battery

Got a new battery for my laptop, and the laptop with the new battery shuts down a few seconds after unplugging the charger. This is not the ubuntu shut down, but a hard one, like what would have happened to a desktop if it was unplugged from power.

Additional facts:

- The bios recognizes the new battery, and can run its calibrate on it, to drain 
  it. Draining takes about 2 hours, with fan and screen running, so the battery is not outright 
  disfunctional.
- It seems that shut down happens on SSD access. I can boot, only on the battery, a clean Ubuntu 16.04 from usb in "live" mode, and it would run until I'd click on the SSD folder to see what's inside. Then it would shut down.
- The battery supplier replaced the battery two times, all three batteries
  have the same problem. No problem with the original battery.

The question is - can this be an Ubuntu problem, perhaps the OS somehow not getting along with the new battery's controller?

Ubuntu: 14.04, Laptop: Samsung np900x.

Update:
There is a BIOS testing utility, as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BIOSandUbuntu). It reports many ACPI related errors - [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24347398/). Not yet sure what to do about them.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful it will be, but could you post the output of `cat /var/log/syslog` at http://paste.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24292852/)    Removed some lines about [UFW BLOCK]. This is system running with charger.

Comment: Do you have any information on the drive? I have some steps to follow.

Comment: @komark please re-post that after you unplug.

Comment: could try the same thing with the boot from usb only on battery. If I do manage to open the terminal, would the syslog be still at '/var/log/syslog'?

Comment: @MarkYisri after unplug, same type of messages until the system shuts down in ~10 of seconds.    I do have information on the drive.

Comment: @Rinzwind Reinstall Ubuntu? This is why I tried to boot from a clean usb. This fails while in "live" mode before install. Means the install would fail too, no?

Comment: Hmm. Yeah. Sorry missed that. I would think it is a hardware problem. Maybe the battery is not making a good enough contact with the system. Have a hardware repair dude have a look at it :)

Comment: @komark - Wait, the syslog is just that? It should be much longer, like over 1,000 lines....

Comment: could be a motherboard issue

Comment: @komark Did you find a solution to this issue? I've got a dell 5510 running ubuntu 16.04. I just replaced the battery with an offbrand battery (because of cost) since the dell battery was swelling and starting to break my trackpad. I am now experiencing the same issue you describe here. When doing seemingly normal things like logging in while on battery, it just shuts off like there was absolutely no power. Did disabling ACPI functions work? I'm not sure it is possible since this machine uses UEFI.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have a system with a buggy or out of spec ACPI firmware. Ideally you should be able to disable ACPI in the BIOS as shown below:

[image: IMG:]

Another option would be to use the acpi=off kernel parameter. You can test this by editing the vmlinuz line at boot and adding the acpi=off parameter. to make it permanent, edit `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor; find the line:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and add the acpi=off parameter to the space separated list of parameters between the quotes.